# date field without time in a datagrid, trunc not working

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, date, datagrid

In my database (oracle 10g) I have in my table :

```
...
Date_ DATE NOT NULL,
...
```

In my WPF application, I plan on using a calendar to insert the date, but for now as a test I've inserted manually like so :

```
..., TO_DATE('21/02/16','DD/MM/YY'), ...
```

The problem is when I display this table from a DataSet into a DataGrid in WPF, it always shows up as 21/02/2016 12:00:00 AM. But `select date_ from tablename;` in the sqlplus command line shows me `21-FEB-2016`, and I also updated the table with `trunc(date_)` in sqlplus but the time still shows in the datagrid

If I try something like

```
query = ("select column1, column2, trunc(date_) from tablename");
```

or

```
query = ("select column1, column2, to_date(date_, 'dd/mm/yyyy') from tablename");
```

then the column name in the datagrid just changes to "trunc(date)" but still shows the time.

Bonus question:

```
query = ("select column1, column2, date_ AS Date from tablename");
```

throws an out of bounds exception, why?

Comment: Where is the c# code?

Comment: `DATE` does not have any format; it's just a number. If you want to format a `DATE` value, use `TO_CHAR()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your problem - in ORA your data stored as date [no hours, min, sec, etc]. But when you load your `DataTable` in your `DataSet`, your .net provider automatically converts your Oracle type into `DateTime`. `DateTime`, as you know, has time part. If you want to show only date, you have 2 ways. You either code special grid column, which will display `<value>.ToString("dd/MM/yy")`, or simply, edit your query to auto-load your date as string, using `to_char`

```
query = "select column1, column2, to_char(date_, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS MyDate  from tablename";
```

Actually, there are many ways of doing it but the principal issue here is that .net types don't match oracle types and somewhere you need to convert something. Usually, you display string representation of a data type. But when you save, you convert input into DB data type.